# Sliding window over a 2D vector, implementation of Marching Squares algorithm

Tags: c++, vectors

I have not used C++ in quite a while and looking for advice/feedback, the code below implements the Marching Squares Algorithm which is detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares).
While the implementation appears correct and gives the same result as the example on the Wikipedia page, I think that some of the code could be improved and I'm looking for general feedback on how.
In particular,

- how I handle vectors
- the 2x2 sliding matrix that moves across the test data
- where I OR in a value

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;


void ApplyThreshold(vector<vector<int>> &Matrix2D, int threshold);
vector<vector<int>> CreateContourMatrix(vector<vector<int>> &pMatrix);

int main()
{

    const int cutOff = 2;//The value on which to base the creation of contours
    vector<vector<int>> matrix;
    //Setup test data
    matrix.push_back(vector<int> { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 });
    matrix.push_back(vector<int> {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, });
    matrix.push_back(vector<int> {1, 3, 3, 3, 1, });
    matrix.push_back(vector<int> {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, });
    matrix.push_back(vector<int> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, });

    vector<vector<int>> pMatrix = matrix;

    ApplyThreshold(pMatrix, cutOff);//Establishthe contours
    auto contourMatrix = CreateContourMatrix(pMatrix);//Build contour shapes
    //Print the result
    for (auto contour_row : contourMatrix)
    {
        for (int element : contour_row)
        {
            std::cout << element << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
/*
 * Move a 2x2 window across a 2d matrix, calculating contour shapes
 */
vector<vector<int>> CreateContourMatrix(vector<vector<int>> &pMatrix)
{
    vector<vector<int>> contourMatrix;
    //vector<int> rows[5];
    for (int i =0;i<pMatrix.size() - 1;i++)
    {
        vector<int> row;//Should this allocation be moved out of the for loop?

        for (int j=0;j<pMatrix[0].size() - 1;j++)//Assume that all rows of the image are the same size
        {
            int shape = 0;
            if (pMatrix[i][j] == 1)
                shape = shape | 8;
            if (pMatrix[i][j + 1] == 1)
                shape = shape | 4;
            if (pMatrix[i+1][j] == 1)
                shape = shape | 1;
            if (pMatrix[i+1][j+1] == 1)
                shape = shape | 2;
            row.push_back(shape);
        }
        contourMatrix.push_back(row);
    }
    return contourMatrix;
}

void ApplyThreshold(vector<vector<int>> &Matrix2D, int threshhold)
{
    for (auto rowVector : Matrix2D)
    {
        for (auto vectorValue : rowVector)
        {
            if (vectorValue >= threshhold)
                vectorValue = 1;
            else
                vectorValue = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't supposed to be a complete implementation, i.e. I don't deal with ambiguous cases or actually create an image of the contours. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple miscellaneous things.

I don't think you need the `vector<int>` for the initialization. eg:

```
matrix.push_back({ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, });
```

You can use references in the for loops, just for good measure. IMO using the type instead of auto makes it easier to read when it's a simple type too.

```
for (auto& contour_row : contourMatrix)
{
    for (int& element : contour_row)
    {
        std::cout << element << '\t';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In `CreateContourMatrix()` the row vector can come out of the for loop. Use `.clear()` or `.fill()` on it inside the loop, then you aren't reallocating.